# Mongodb not able to create certificate with CN as fqdn for sharded mongo db cluster

Tags: mongodb, openssl

As per the Mongodb documentation, https://docs.mongodb.com/kubernetes-operator/master/tutorial/secure-tls/#create-tls-certificates-for-a-sharded-cluster

*"For each replica set or sharded cluster member, the **Common Name**, also known as the Domain Name, for that member’s certificate must match the FQDN of the POD on which this cluster member is deployed.

The FQDN name in each certificate has the following syntax: pod-name.service-name.namespace.svc.cluster.local. This name is different for each Pod hosting a member of the replica set or a sharded cluster."*

for default sharded cluster we have below fqdn for the pod which is of 70 characters and due to which openssl throwing error "string too long".

pod names for sharded cluster are like
my-sharded-cluster-0-0, my-sharded-cluster-0-1 etc..

OpenSSL error details

openssl req -out mongodb.svc.csr -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout my-sharded-cluster-0-0.key -subj "/CN=my-sharded-cluster-0-0.my-sharded-cluster-sh.mongodb.svc.cluster.local/O=my organization"
*Generating a RSA private key
writing new private key to 'my-sharded-cluster-0-0.key'
problems making Certificate Request
139674817741952:error:0D07A097:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_mbstring_ncopy:string too long:../crypto/asn1/a_mbstr.c:107:maxsize=64*

Comment: I believe you can have a shorter common name, but the cert must then support the FQDN as an Subject Alternative Name (SAN).

Comment: Yes, I can give it a try with SAN. "Documentation bit confusing on that part since it clearly says common name must match the fqdn of the pod"

Comment: I have used shorter name for metadata.name in mongodb shard yaml to reduce the length of CN.